# Python - Recommended way to show game save files to user

Tags: python, deserialization, pickle, savestate

Searching online, I found a lot of tutorials for saving/loading program data into/from files. However, I already know this (I am using Python `pickle` to serialize/de-serialize objects).

My question is how should the files be displayed to the users? Especially if there are multiple files, **I want to display summary information from each save file** for the user to choose which file to load.

Some options I am considering are as follows:

1. **Load all save files, display key information.**

   This is the simplest solution, but I keep thinking there must be a better way?
2. **Store metadata of the save files in another file.**

   Read this file to display key information of each save file.

   My question is do I need to worry about consistency/integrity between this meta file and the actual save files? E.g., if a save operation successfully update the game save file, but the game crashes before the meta file can be updated, the data is then corrupted.
3. **Put the metadata in the filename**

   May work when the metadata is only a few number of fields. But is this even a good idea?
4. **Put the metadata as header information in the file**

   Then, read only the header part to display. However, I do not know how to implement this using `pickle`

I am not making an overly huge game, but I still hope to implement a best practice approach. So I am looking for a simple stupid solution, not some overly complex one, but still hopefully cleaner/not as stupid as option 1 above.

Comment: Assuming there are more than two or three files (for which 1. would be enough), an approach is to add metadata to the individual file and create a cache file with metadata of the other files. The cache may contain additional info like modification date and size of each other file to ensure consistency or it could be deleted each time before a regular file is created/updated/deleted. The cache file is then recreated when needed.

Comment: Well, you're thinking along the right lines.  All of these are valid options, although I don't like #3.  #4 would be the best option, I'd think.  You just need to figure out if you can skip past a header before reading pickled information.  My guess would be that this is possible.  #3 could be made to be pretty safe.  You could write the new file along with a copy of the index to temporary files.  Then, once they're written, rename them both to move them into place.  Choose the best order to do the renames for consistency if one of the renames fails, which wouldn't be likely.

Comment: I like Michaels' idea of having the index file be reconstructable from the individual game save files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272493/python-recommended-way-to-show-game-save-files-to-user#comment97276217_55272493) and [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272493/python-recommended-way-to-show-game-save-files-to-user#comment97276221_55272493) for the suggestions! I think it will work very well for my case.

1. Each save file will have an accompanying metadata file, e.g., `save023.dat` and `save023.meta`
2. To ensure consistency between the pair, write operations are first performed on a temporary file `save023.dat.temp`
3. On success, update the meta file `save023.meta`
4. Finally, on success of step 3, rename `save023.dat.temp` to `save023.dat`
5. In any case if the meta file is missing, or if the program detects that there exists a `.temp` file, it will re-generate the `.meta` file (and then rename the `.temp` file if applicable)